# Python 2.7 : Remove elements from a multidimensional list

Tags: list, python-2.7

Basically, I have a 3dimensional list (it is a list of tokens, where the first dimension is for the text, second for the sentence, and third for the word).

Addressing an element in the list (lets call it mat) can be done for example:
mat[2][3][4]. That would give us the fifth word or the fourth sentence in the third text.

But, some of the words are just symbols like '.' or ',' or '?'. I need to remove all of them. I thought to do that with a procedure:

```
    def removePunc(mat):
        newMat = []
        newText = []
        newSentence = []
        for text in mat:
           for sentence in text:
               for word in sentence:
                   if word not in " !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\\:;'<>?,./\"":
                       newSentence.append(word)  
               newText.append(newSentence)
           newMat.append(newText)
        return newMat
```

Now, when I try to use that:

```
    finalMat = removePunc(mat)
```

it is giving me the same list (mat is a 3 dimensional list). My idea was to iterate over the list and remove only the 'words' which are actually punctuation symbols.

I don't know what I am doing wrong but surely there is a simple logical mistake.

Edit: I need to keep the structure of the array. So, words of the same sentence should still be in the same sentence (just without the 'punctuation symbol' words). Example:

```
    a = [[['as', '.'], ['w', '?', '?']], [['asas', '23', '!'], ['h', ',', ',']]]
```

after the changes should be:

```
    a = [[['as'], ['w']], [['asas', '23'], ['h']]]
```

Thanks for reading and/or giving me a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that your data are not organized as you think they are. And although I am usually not the one to propose regular expressions, I think in your case they may be among the best solutions.
I would also suggest that instead of eliminating non-alphabetic characters from words, you process sentences

```
>>> import re
>>> non_word = re.compile(r'\W+') # If your sentences may 
>>> sentence = '''The formatting sucks, but the only change that I've made to your code was shortening the "symbols" string to one character. The only issue that I can identify is either with the "symbols" string (though it looks like all chars in it are properly escaped) that you used, or the punctuation is not actually separate words'''
>>> words = re.split(non_word, sentence)
>>> words
['The', 'formatting', 'sucks', 'but', 'the', 'only', 'change', 'that', 'I', 've', 'made', 'to', 'your', 'code', 'was', 'shortening', 'the', 'symbols', 'string', 'to', 'one', 'character', 'The', 'only', 'issue', 'that', 'I', 'can', 'identify', 'is', 'either', 'with', 'the', 'symbols', 'string', 'though', 'it', 'looks', 'like', 'all', 'chars', 'in', 'it', 'are', 'properly', 'escaped', 'that', 'you', 'used', 'or', 'the', 'punctuation', 'is', 'not', 'actually', 'separate', 'words']
>>>
```

Comment: Cheers!

I'll need to verify if the data are really how I think they are. That might be a problem. On the other side, I really don't understand your solution (haven'd done regular expressions before).

The data are processed. Every word is a member of a 3dimensional matrix, where the first dimension is the text, second the sentence and third the word. I need to keep the structure like this because I have to further process it (doing natural language processing).

I still am not sure if I really need the 'symbol' words to remove, but it is one of the possible options.

Comment: @IsmailElezi, the problem is - if your data was the way you think it was, your solution would have worked. Essentially my solution is equivalent to regular string __split__ - only with regular expression that means "one or more non-word symbols"

Comment: Do you know, how I can do this but not seperating words in apostrophe?

By that I mean, the output to be like this, with the only change that words like "I've" to continue being "I've" instead of being seperated into "I" and "ve".

Comment: I found how to do that.

Big thanks to you sir, no my code is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote seems solid and it looks like "it should work", but only if this:

> But, some of the words are just symbols like '.' or ',' or '?'

is actually fulfilled.
I would actually expect the symbols to not be separate from words, so instead of:

```
["Are", "you", "sure", "?"] #example sentence
```

you would rather have:

```
["Are", "you", "sure?"] #example sentence
```

If this is the case, you would need to go along the lines of:

```
def removePunc(mat):
    newMat = []
    newText = []
    newSentence = []
    newWord = ""
    for text in mat:
       for sentence in text:
           for word in sentence:
               for char in word:
                   if char not in " !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\\:;'<>?,./\"":
                       newWord += char
                   newSentence.append(newWord)  
           newText.append(newSentence)
       newMat.append(newText)
    return newMat
```

Comment: No, actually, I would need them completely removed.

I also pointed out (just a minute ago) a small example of how I would expect the result to be.

Cheers!

Comment: Ran your code with Python 2.7.9:
    sentence = ["These", "are", "words", "!"]
    text = [sentence]
    mat = [text]
    def removePunc(mat):
        newMat = []
        newText = []
        newSentence = []
        for text in mat:
            for sentence in text:
                for word in sentence:
                    if word not in "!":
                        newSentence.append(word)
                newText.append(newSentence)
            newMat.append(newSentence)
        return newMat

    removePunc(mat)
    >> [[["These", "are", "words"]]]
    sentence2 = ["These", "are", "words!"]

Comment: The formatting sucks, but the only change that I've made to your code was shortening the "symbols" string to one character. The only issue that I can identify is either with the "symbols" string (though it looks like all chars in it are properly escaped) that you used, or the punctuation is not actually separate words.

Comment: This is excruciatingly ineffective solution

Comment: Guess it is, but it builds directly on Ismail's suggestion, allowing him to understand fully what it does and to modify it later if needed. Still, gotta say that your solution is more elegant and pythonic.

Comment: Just looked at the output, and it is:
        [[['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h'],
          ['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h'],
          ['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h'],
          ['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h']],
         [['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h'],
          ['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h'],
          ['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h'],
          ['as', 'w', 'asas', '23', 'h']]]

This surely isn't what I was expecting.

Comment: It would have been much easier if in the original post you have posted the "mat" you were working with, the output that you have received and the output that you wanted to receive. Still, good that you have found a solution.

Comment: It was a very big matrix (thousands of words there), so it was impossible to post it. For that I used a toy example on my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found it. As expected, it was a very small logical mistake that was always there but couldn't see it. Here is the working solution:

```
def removePunc(mat):
newMat = []
for text in mat:
   newText = []
   for sentence in text:
       newSentence = []
       for word in sentence:
           if word not in " !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\\:;'<>?,./\"":
               newSentence.append(word)  
       newText.append(newSentence)
   newMat.append(newText)
return newMat
```